# How to set Custom Message when throwing Exception from RegistrationHandler

Tags: error-messages, custom, open-id-connect

I successfully integrated an Open Id connector(via Auth. Provider) with our Salesforce environment, we can log in successfully. But sometimes you should not get access because you don't have the right roles in the IDM-system (system where all users are defined outside of Salesforce).

When such an exception gets thrown, we always land on the same page with the same generic error:

[image: Error]

I would like to set a custom message right there, because in the URL I see that there is the following
-Community-URL-/_nc_external/identity/sso/ui/AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=REGISTRATION_HANDLER_ERROR&ErrorDescription=-custom error message-+%28USR-06%29&ProviderId=-providerId-&startURL=-startUrl-
(I changed some identifiers to generic values, everything in between - - )

So you see the error description is available in the url. Is there a way I can adapt this generic page to show the URL Parameter(ErrorDescription) instead of the default message as in the image.

If something is not clear, let me know, I'll try to give some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by creating a custom component that we put on the 'Login Error' page of the Community. This component reads a code in the URL to display the correct message.